# Detect union access errors in C

Tags: c, code-analysis

Let's say I have a variant type in C implemented as an annotated union:

```
enum var_mode {
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B
};

union var_data {
    int a;
    double b;
};

struct var_type {
    enum var_mode mode;
    // 'a' member only valid if mode is TYPE_A, 'b' only if TYPE_B.
    union var_data data;
};
```

Whether or not type-punning this union is undefined behaviour or implementation defined behaviour depends on the standard being written to  (I think). **However** in my program I consider it an error, and would like to detect it. For example, this would be an error:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct var_type example;
    example.mode = TYPE_B;
    example.data.b = 3.5e8;

    printf("Data: %d\n", example.data.a);
}
```

Compare it to the usefulness of detecting memory leaks, which are not undefined behaviour but generally considered errors in a program. Or to unsigned integer wrapping — it's not undefined behaviour but tools exist to detect it as an error (eg. LLVM Clang's `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`) because it's often unintentional.

Is there a tool — maybe like Valgrind's suite of tools or LLVM Clang's sanitisers — that will allow me to detect such errors without substantial refactoring of an existing code base? My preference would be to not rely on the annotation ie. ideally it would work with bare unions, since the underlying assumption is that the programmer isn't perfect, but I'll consider anything.

Comment: Note about the tags: *programming* had no description, and I'm not sure if it's too broad. There seemed to be no tags for tools for eg. development, code analysis, error checking. Open to ideas.

Comment: To detect an error in union misuse, it seems that what you want to know is if a you have a union with members X and Y, that the code assigns to X and then reads from Y.  That is surely a mistake; I'm not a C language lawyer but I assume its undefined behavior.    ....

Comment: ...  However, your example insists that you have union  that has an an associated tag variable (you happened to put them both in a single struct) and that accesses to the union must only match the state of the tag variable.  How is such a tool supposed to know where the tag variable instance is, for an instance union?  How is it supposed to know which states of the tag variable, correspond to which union members?  We assume such  a tool isn't going to read your comment line.

Comment: If you can define specific rules for these (e.g., "any struct containing an enum followed by a union should be treated as a tagged union and investigated"), I might have an answer.

Comment: @IraBaxter FYI it's not UB, it's implementation defined. Some people use it for eg. serialising data on embedded systems to be sent to other ICs. But it is often a mistake, you're right.

Comment: @IraBaxter But I'd like it to be detected as an error even in an untagged union TBH. The tagging in my example code is more to illustrate to readers, via use of a common idiom, that this is a very unambiguous error.

Comment: You didn't answer the question as to how the tool is supposed to know which unions have associated tags, and what the tags means.   You've added the problem of diagnoising errors in unions without tags.  What is the specific condition you want the tool to detect?

Comment: @IraBaxter Note in the question I say "My preference would be to not rely on the annotation ie. ideally it would work with bare unions". It *doesn't* have to know which unions have tags, I added that detail not because it's a constraint for me but because it might be for such a tool.

Comment: @IraBaxter The condition I want the tool to detect is an access via one union member when it was last written to via a different one. How the tool does this isn't hugely relevant to me, just like how Valgrind does things isn't. Interesting to know, sure, and useful when considering how it might fail, but ultimately not necessary to know in detail.

Comment: OK, so your requirement matches my second comment.

Comment: @IraBaxter Indeed. The tagging was probably a red herring more than it was helpful, sorry.